# Flattening a Binary Tree

Tags: java

I have this below Data Structure.

[image]

The output will be like

```
m - n - o - p - q - r - s -t
```

Please review the below code and let me know if any optimization can be done.

```
public class Application {

    public static Node root = null;
    public static Node temp = root;
    public static Node anotherTemp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node m = new Node("m");
        Node n = new Node("n");
        Node o = new Node("o");
        Node p = new Node("p");
        m.setDown(n);
        n.setDown(o);
        o.setDown(p);

        Node q = new Node("q");
        Node r = new Node("r");
        Node s = new Node("s");

        m.setRight(q);
        q.setDown(r);
        r.setDown(s);

        Node t = new Node("t");
        q.setRight(t);
        root = new Node(m.getValue());
        temp = root;

        anotherTemp = m;

        flattern(m);
        // Here is my output
        System.out.println(temp);
    }

    public static void flattern(Node m) {

        if (m.getRight() == null)
            return;

        while (m.getDown() != null) {
            if (!m.getValue().equals("m")) {
                root.setRight(new Node(m.getValue()));
                m = m.getDown();
                root = root.getRight();
            }
            else
                m = m.getDown();
        }
        if (m.getDown() == null) {
            root.setRight(new Node(m.getValue()));
            if (anotherTemp.getRight() != null) {
                anotherTemp = anotherTemp.getRight();
                root.getRight().setRight(new Node(anotherTemp.getValue()));
                root = root.getRight();
            }
        }

        if (m.getDown() == null)
            flattern(anotherTemp);
        System.out.println(temp);
        System.out.println(root);
    }

}

class Node {
    String value;
    Node right;
    Node down;

    Node(String val) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Node getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(Node right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public Node getDown() {
        return down;
    }

    public void setDown(Node down) {
        this.down = down;
    }

}
```

Comment: You misspelt `flatten` as `flattern`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Possible bug

If you were to set a right node to the node `r` with

```
r.setRight(new Node("v"));
```

the result would not contain this node.

#### OOP paradigm

There are several fundamental issues with your solution. Mainly, it breaks completely the OOP paradigm; this is shown by:

- The use of static global variables:

  ```
  public static Node root = null;
  public static Node temp = root;
  public static Node anotherTemp;
  ```

  [This is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7026563/1743880): this creates variables that can be seen and modified by anyone, when in reality, they only make sense when flattening the nodes.
- The flattening algorithm depends on the value itself!

  ```
  if (!m.getValue().equals("m")) {
  ```

  The issue with this line is that you have just made your algorithm dependent on your data. It cannot flatten any node since `"m"` is hard-coded. If tomorrow your first node has a value of `"a"`, it will be broken.

In Object-Oriented Programming, you should give behaviour to objects. Your object in this case is a `Node`, and you are trying to flatten it. Therefore, it makes sense to have a method `flatten()` inside the class `Node`: any node can be flattened and it is the responsibility of a `Node` to be able to flatten itself.

Let's reason through what it means for a node `n` to be flattened:

1. The new `right` of node `n` will be the result of flatting what was below it.
2. After that, the right-most node of `n` will have at its right set to the flattened previous right of `n`.

This shows a simple recursive solution:

```
class Node {

    // ...

    public Node flatten() {
        Node node = new Node(value);
        Node prevRight = right;
        if (down != null) {
            node.setRight(down.flatten());
        }
        if (prevRight != null) {
            Node rightMost = node;
            while (rightMost.getRight() != null) {
                rightMost = rightMost.getRight();
            }
            rightMost.setRight(prevRight.flatten());
        }
        return node;
    }

}
```

Be careful of typos also, `flattern` is mis-spelled: it should be `flatten`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    while (m.getDown() != null) {
        if (!m.getValue().equals("m")) {
            root.setRight(new Node(m.getValue()));
            m = m.getDown();
            root = root.getRight();
        }
        else
            m = m.getDown();
    }
```

Here, in both cases, you do `m = m.getDown()`. Since the other function calls don't seem to be directly related, we can extract it like so:

```
    while (m.getDown() != null) {
        if (!m.getValue().equals("m")) {
            root.setRight(new Node(m.getValue()));
            root = root.getRight();
        }
        m = m.getDown();
    }
```

This also gets rid of the `else` without braces.

Moving on..

```
    while (m.getDown() != null) {
        if (!m.getValue().equals("m")) {
            root.setRight(new Node(m.getValue()));
            root = root.getRight();
        }
        m = m.getDown();
    }
    if (m.getDown() == null) {
```

The while loop has no `break` inside of it, so the only way you'll get past the while loop is by having `m.getDown()` equal `null`. Which is what you check for afterwards.

That if check can go, as it's always true.

Similarily, later on, you check for `m.getDown() == null` again. Since there were no alterations to the `down` variable, it's still going to be null. Remove the if-check.